# What else give almost 100% discount/Rebate?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I have enough workshop with adjacency bonus.

It seems that I can build effectively infinite whatever I want for $1 each. Firestorm, any vehicles. However, guns and instantly build items cost remain the same.

Am I correct?

If so, what turns it on?

The workshop or the engineer?

Here are some references that's not clear
http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Workshop

It says that vehicles, facilities, and foundry updates are discounted. However, weapons like EMP cannot is also discounted. It seems that anything that took a while to produce is discounted.

Also it seems that the CONNECTION between workshops and not the workshop itself that turns this on.

I just want to make sure.

Comment: "what turns it on?" seems a bit unclear to me. I believe you are asking which of your holdings activate the game feature, and have answered as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your question is not entirely clear, the wiki article you linked to, and my own experience agree on how the workshop/engineer economic savings works. There are two factors in play here. The first factor is that having more engineers decreases the initial cost of items. Building workshops gives you engineers and thus, as a side effect, lowers the cost of items somewhat.

Workshops also have an adjacency bonus that they give. For every adjacency (pair of similar buildings next to each other) you are refunded a certain amount of the cost at the end of construction. This only applies to vehicles, foundry projects, ad base facilities, **not** to items. It also is only applied at the end of construction. You have to spend the resources, wait for the project to finish, then you get them back.

As for the first part, you are approximately correct. If the cost contains any Elerium or Alien Alloy component you also end up spending one of each of those.

Comment: Just want to be clear, it's the connection and NOT the workshop it self right?

Comment: Indeed, the connection is what's important for the rebate. The only direct advantage from the workshop is the engineers it gives you.